# Удалить из переменной все звездочки

Tags: bash

Как удалить из переменной все встречающиеся звездочки. Переменная представляет из себя текст и там попадаются символы "*". Нужно их все удалить. Желательно с помощью только bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

например:

```
$ s='*123*45'; echo ${s//\*/}
12345
```

см. `$ man bash`:

- `${параметр/шаблон/замена}` — в значении параметра `шаблон` заменяется на строку `замена` (сам параметр остаётся неизменным)
- `\*` — т.к. символ звёздочка имеет специальное значение, для его буквальной трактовки перед ним надо поставить `\`
- если шаблон начинается с символа `/`, то заменяются все вхождения (например, `${s/\*/}` заменит только первую звёздочку)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "AAAB**YY**H***" | sed -r 's/[\*]+//g'
```

Comment: Разве ```\``` не лишний?

Comment: @Qwertiy, тут и sed лишний.